# How do I use an array with a value with a single quote in a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO objects(objId, objectId, objectCategory, SortOrder, Name) VALUES('{$obj_id}', '{$object_id}', '{$object_category}', '{$sortorder}', 'My " . $objecta['Name'] . "')")or die(mysql_error());
```

This code fails when `$objecta['Name']` has a single quote in it. I can't seem to be able to quote everything so that it works even if `$objecta['Name']` has a single quote in it.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) You should escape your input. `mysql_real_escape_string($objecta['Name'])` This ensures that things like the `'` character are escaped, i.e. `\'` which allows the insert to happen.

2) `mysql_*` extension is deprecated and you should really at least use `mysqli_*` or pdo or another database driver. Using prepared statements in one of these other database drivers accomplishes the same as what I said above.

Comment: One thing: Escaping is not the right way. Prepared, parameterized Statements are the way to go. MySQLi and PDO supports it.